# how to access data on RAID10 (consisting of 2 disks) using only 1 disk?

Tags: raid, mdadm

A long time ago I setup a RAID consisting of 2 disks. I wanted more than else safety/redundancy and indeed I think I wanted a RAID1. Now I have only access to one of those 2 disks and looking at it I see

```
root@pc:~# mdadm --examine /dev/sdd1
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : XXXXXeXX:bXdXXXXc:adXXacXb:XXcXbaXX
  Creation Time : Thu Aug  X XX:XX:XX XXXX
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Wed Dec 28 12:23:27 2011
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 7a4c440 - correct
         Events : 694

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 64K
```

Suprise I might have a raid10. Now the thing is that I cannot really understand well how this was reasonible with only 2 disks to start with.

What I would like to ask is if and how I could get access to the data stored in the RAID10 (2 disks) using only the 1 remaining disk.

As a bonus I do not really understand what is the difference (in the case of 2 disks, between linux MD RAID10 and RAID1), maybe this is part of the riddle?

Comment: If the disks both have two partitions on them then you have a total of four partitions, enough for RAID 10.  Not that this would be sensible, but I have seen it before in the wild where a manufactorer recommended RAID 10 and a technician tried to set up up on a 2 disk server. So: Technically possible: yes. Sensible: Heck no.

Answer (score 1):

yes I could! I have used the following way to access the data.

```
$ mdadm -f -R /dev/md0
mdadm --examine --scan
```

This started the RAID10 (which indeed is somewhat of a oddity to myself, especially how I ended up, and what makes it different to a simple RAID1)

Anyway the [Linux MD RAID10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_MD_RAID_10#Linux_MD_RAID_10) was presented like this for 2 disks

```
2 drives         3 drives          4 drives
--------         ----------        --------------
A1  A1           A1  A1  A2        A1  A1  A2  A2
A2  A2           A2  A3  A3        A3  A3  A4  A4
A3  A3           A4  A4  A5        A5  A5  A6  A6
A4  A4           A5  A6  A6        A7  A7  A8  A8
..  ..           ..  ..  ..        ..  ..  ..  ..
```

At least in this graphics I cannot see a big difference in between raid1 and raid10 setup (in case of only 2 disks)